# How to move qtip2 tooltip to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I have an element with a qtip2 tooltip applied to it. See JSFfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/inodb/y7xqvceL/2/. The element in the example is an `<a id="test">` element. I want to move said tooltip to another `<a id="test2">` element programmatically. I imagine I should either

1. update the target of the existing tooltip or
2. copy all the options of the original and create a new qtip on the second anchor element supplying all those options

The context to the problem is that I have a library which shows tooltips when hovering over a SVG `<circle>` elements. I want to wrap those circles in a `<g>` tag such that I can put a `<text>` on the circle. The tooltip however only works on the circle, so if you hover over the text, the tooltip is not displayed. I figured moving the qtip2 tooltip from the `<circle>` element to the `<g>` element would be easiest.

Comment: You should try first...then ask questions here stating what didn't work if you do encounter problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I am reusing qtip2 tooltips & their options, I find it helpful to create a function that generates or destroys the tooltip.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/y7xqvceL/8/

```
//custom function to create tooltips with similar options or destroy them
function GenerateTooltip(tooltipElement, isCreating) {
    //if creating the tooltip, use these options
    if (isCreating) {
        $(tooltipElement).qtip({
            content: {
                text: 'Tooltip content that should be moved',
            },
        });
    } else {
        //if isCreating == false, destroy the tooltip specified
        tooltipElement.qtip('destroy', true);
    }
}
//...
GenerateTooltip($("#test"), false); //first destroy old tooltip
GenerateTooltip($("#test2"), true); //create new tooltip
```

If that is too complicated or this operation only needs to happen once, I would recommend destroying the first tooltip and creating the new one manually.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/y7xqvceL/9/

```
//this button click moves the tooltip to the other element
$("#move-tt").click(function () {
    $('#test').qtip('destroy', true); //destroy old tooltip

    $("#test2").qtip({ //create new tooltip
        content: {
            text: 'Tooltip content that should be moved',
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved the problem in a similar way to your recommendation. In my case the library doesn't expose the function to generate the tooltip, so I think it would still be cleaner to move/copy the tooltip in some way instead of creating a new one. If that is impossible than your solution is prolly the best one.

Comment: I don't believe "moving" it is possible. Once it is created, it is stuck.